# duplicate symbol error in Objective-C and Xcode

Tags: objective-c

I am getting the following error when trying to compile a simple program I wrote (a cipher). I understand that I have a duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Cipher, but I am unsure of what is happening to cause this. I tried to check to see if I accidentally imported stuff twice, but all was good. Any help is much appreciated! :)

```
Ld "/Users/Lukas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Caesar_Shift-drfzwlpgygkbcifoefghycamkoya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Caesar Shift.app/Caesar Shift" normal i386
    cd "/Users/Lukas/Documents/Programming/iPhone Applications/Caesar Shift"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/Lukas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Caesar_Shift-drfzwlpgygkbcifoefghycamkoya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Lukas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Caesar_Shift-drfzwlpgygkbcifoefghycamkoya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/Lukas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Caesar_Shift-drfzwlpgygkbcifoefghycamkoya/Build/Intermediates/Caesar Shift.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Caesar Shift.build/Objects-normal/i386/Caesar Shift.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o "/Users/Lukas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Caesar_Shift-drfzwlpgygkbcifoefghycamkoya/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Caesar Shift.app/Caesar Shift"

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Cipher in /Users/Lukas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Caesar_Shift-drfzwlpgygkbcifoefghycamkoya/Build/Intermediates/Caesar Shift.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Caesar Shift.build/Objects-normal/i386/CaesarShiftViewController.o and /Users/Lukas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Caesar_Shift-drfzwlpgygkbcifoefghycamkoya/Build/Intermediates/Caesar Shift.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Caesar Shift.build/Objects-normal/i386/CaesarShiftAppDelegate.o for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Any relevant code?  The two files mentioned in the linker, and the header where the class is originally declared would be helpful

Comment: The linker doesn't lie! =) You've either re-declared or imported `Cipher` in CaesarShiftViewController or the CaesarShiftAppDelegate. Double-check your `.pch` file too.

Answer (score 4):

Here are two likely reasons for this error:

1. You have put `@implementation Cipher` in a header file (probably the `Cipher.h` header file), and you've imported that header file in both `CaesarShiftViewController.m` and `CaesarShiftAppDelegate.m`.  An `@implementation` statement goes in a `.m` file, not a `.h` file.
2. You have accidentally imported `Cipher.m` in both `CaesarShiftViewController.m` and `CaesarShiftAppDelegate.m`.  You were supposed to import `Cipher.h` (notice the suffix!).

As HachiEthan pointed out in a comment, you might have imported `Cipher.m` in your `Caeser Shift-Prefix.pch` file (in the “Supporting Files” group).  This file is automatically imported by all `.m` files, so it would have the same effect as my #2 above.